# Time Validation in swift3

Tags: time, swift3

How to check, whether the entered time is 'hh:mm' format or not. If in hours place entered greater than 24 and minutes place entered greater than 60 then display invalid time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like this :

```
let dateAsString = "23:55"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAsString) {
    print(date)
} else {
    print("Not a valid date") // if dateAsString is > 23:59 or not in HH:mm format
}
```